# Gap between tag buttons diminishes after in-place refresh of the question body

Tags: bug, status-review, tags, design

The tags under every question:

> [image: Normal state of tags]

When an in-place refresh of the question body happens (which is either because you have edited the question in-place or because you have clicked the "question was modified, click to refresh" banner), the tags get much closer together, and the "Edit tags" link disappears:

> [image: Tags smashed together]

Completely refreshing the page fixes that.

Comment: Just in case anybody mentions the missing "Edit tags": [Inline tag editor disappears after live refreshing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382180)

Comment: This can be manually demonstrated on this question by executing `StackExchange.realtime.reloadPosts([422741]);` in the browser console. The HTML which is used for `realtime.reloadPosts()` is substantially different for the tags than what's used in the main question page view. That difference probably prevents the initialization of the inline tag editor, but I haven't looked at the JavaScript code to verify that. I seem to recall something along these lines being previously reported, either here on MSO or on MSE, but I'm not finding it and could be misremembering the details.

Comment: @VLAZ I would be not at all surprised to learn that both problems have the same cause. In fact, I think Makyen already evidenced that.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Overall, the in-page reload has steadily been drifting away from the regular load. See also [Editing (or live-refreshing) a post that you follow resets the text of the Follow button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380954)